# Objective-c regex not working like it should

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, regex

I have a very long string. For example:

```
"Dit kwam ik tegen als ik naar beneden scrollde [htag]feedback[/htag]"
```

Like you can see my string contains [htag]word[/htag]. Now I want to get these words.

I'm using the followin regex

```
\\[htag\\]\\w+\\[\\htag]$
```

But it is not working.

Any help ?

Comment: check your second htag it has forward slash `\\[htag\\]\\w+\\[\/htag]$`

Comment: @PratyushaTerli When I use that regex I get a warning : "Unknown escape sequence '\/'"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\\[htag\\]\\w+\\[/htag\\]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]